# Finding Modulus of Complex Rational Function $f(z) = \frac{z-2a+a^2\bar{z}}{1-a\bar{z}-\bar{a}z + |a|^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

As the title says, I am to find the modulus of $f(z) = \frac{z-2a+a^2\bar{z}}{1-a\bar{z}-\bar{a}z + |a|^2}$ where $a,z \in \mathbb{C}$.

I'm a bit confused as to where to start. Would I translate the function into Cartesian form first? If so, I'm not sure how to start.

Thanks anyway.

Comment: You should recognize the denominator from your other [recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2305936/complex-functions-analysis-fz-fracz-a1-baraz/2305944). Is there any additional condition, such that $\,|z|=1\,$, here too?

Comment: @dxiv The denominator is exactly the same from my previous question, I just applied the condition $|z|=1$ to it. I am to show that if $|z|=1$ and $1-\bar{a}z \neq 0$ $\Rightarrow$ $|f(z)|=1$

Comment: `if |z|=1` The question does not mention that condition. You should edit it in.

Comment: @dxiv after applying all the conditions I am left with the function above, I just need to find the modulus of it

Comment: If the problem specifies $|z|=1$ and you are working on that assumption, then you must spell that out in the body of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming (as mentioned by OP in a comment) that $|z|^2=1 \iff z \bar z = 1 \iff \bar z = \cfrac{1}{z}\,$:

$$\require{cancel}
f(z)=\frac{\cfrac{1}{\bar z}-2a+a^2 \bar z}{1-a\bar{z}-\bar{a}z + |a|^2|z|^2}=\frac{\left(\cfrac{1}{\bar z}-a\right)\bcancel{\left(1-a \bar z\right)}}{(1- \bar a z)\bcancel{(1-a \bar z)}}=\frac{1}{\bar z}\cdot\frac{1 - a \bar z}{1-\bar a z}
$$

Then, using that $\,\overline{1 - \bar a z}=1-\overline{\bar a z}=1-a \bar z\,$:

$$
|f(z)|=\left|\frac{1}{\bar z}\right|\cdot\left|\frac{1 - a \bar z}{1-\bar a z}\right|=1 \cdot \left|\frac{\overline{1 - \bar a z}}{1-\bar a z}\right|=1
$$