# Showing $f(z) = \frac{z-a}{1-\bar{a}z}$ is a Moebius Transformation Given Conditions

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

As the title suggests, I want to show that $f(z) = \frac{z-a}{1-\bar{a}z}$ where $z,a \in \mathbb{C}$ is a Moebius transformation with $|a|<1$ and $1-a\bar{a} \neq 0$

I'm uncertain as to how to start. 
 Any help would be appreciated. 
 Thanks.

Comment: Well, what are the conditions for a function to be a Möbius transformation?

Comment: @Chappers We vaguely went over Moebius Transformations in lecture,  but not in detail. Does it have something to do with the derivative of the function and whether or not it equals zero?

Comment: By definition this transformation is Möbius so long as $ad-bc = 1\cdot 1-a\bar a\ne 0$. Note that $1-a\bar a= 1-|a|^2>0$ always. Perhaps you typoed and meant "automorphism of the unit disc"?

Comment: I was given the exact question to work on, It may be a mistake on the instructors end.

Comment: @AdamHughes Good guess. The automorphism part was [answered yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2305936/complex-functions-analysis-fz-fracz-a1-baraz).

Comment: @user2965071 I would confirm, since he has literally given you the answer in the statement if that's so.

Comment: See Theorem 4 in (http://www.johno.dk/mathematics/moebius.pdf).

Comment: $|a|<1 \implies 1-a\bar{a} \neq 0$, so you don't need the second condition...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Möbius transformation $T$ is most simply defined as a nonconstant fractional linear transformation: the latter means
$$ T(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}. $$
To see what nonconstant needs, let $z$ and $w$ be distinct points. Then a calculation shows
$$ T(z) - T(w) = \frac{(ad-bc)(z-w)}{(cz+d)(cw+d)}, $$
so if $z \neq w$, $T(z) \neq T(w)$ if and only if $ad-bc \neq 0$. So in fact, $T$ is injective if and only if it is nonconstant.

---

So, since your function is already of the form $(az+b)/(cz+d)$, you just have to check that $ad-bc \neq 0$.